# put a html file into a docker image and run a container

Tags: html, docker, dockerfile

I'm hitting an issue.

I'm trying to copy an html file into a docker image and run a container with that image.

This is my Dockerfile

```sh
FROM php:7.0-apache

COPY index.html /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

This is my HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1 style="color: #5e9ca0;">You can edit <span style="color: #2b2301;">this demo</span> text!</h1>
      <h2 style="color: #2e6c80;">How to use the editor:</h2>
      <h2 style="color: #2e6c80;">Cleaning options.</h2>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note: I've put my html file in the same folder as my Dockerfile.

I build my image `docker build -t my_2nd_img .` then I run it `docker run --name sec my_2nd_img`.

Issue is I have a `404 page not found` when I tried to reach it on my browser with `http://localhost`.

I tried to see if there was an issue with the logs by running `docker logs <id_of_my_container>`

Nothing in the logs, as you can see below.

```
[Sun Apr 11 17:36:06.140641 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.0.33 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 11 17:36:06.140806 2021] [core:notice] [pid 8] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Any ideas are welcomed as I do not see what is incorrect.

Comment: *I have a `404 page not found` when I tried to reach it on my browser.* > What do you try to access in your browser?

Comment: Hi @β.εηοιτ.βε, the localhost. Let me update my quesiton

Comment: Does your `docker run` command have a `-p` option?  Without it, you won't be able to make requests to the container from the host.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, no p option

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I followed your answer. When I ran `docker ps -a`, I can see the port `0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp`. yet when I go even with a private browser with `0.0.0.0:80`, I still have a `404 page not found`

Comment: Why do you now want to go to `0.0.0.0`? Keep using *localhost*.

Comment: ok @β.εηοιτ.βε trying on my other laptop, just in case something is missing.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tips first:

```sh
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

and

```sh
EXPOSE 80
```

are not needed in your *Dockerfile*, because [they do belong in the parent image your are using already](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.0-apache/images/sha256-e157230a43f4ba259e9c65c0315180a91ed08438d13a3491e9195472dcb44c80?context=explore).

---

Now your issue is the fact that the image is exposing a port but that you are not publishing it to your host.

This would be done at the run time with:

```sh
docker run -p 80:80 --name sec my_2nd_img
```

<sup>*Linked documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports*</sup>

And this will work with something as simple as

```sh
FROM php:7.0-apache

COPY index.html /var/www/html/
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

---

A simple way to debug those kind of issues is to run

```
docker ps
```

This would give something like:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
531d1836653f   cdbaa2128e9f   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   3 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   80/tcp    busy_galois
```

Now if you look closely at the `PORTS` column, you will realise that it exposes the port `80` to the internal Docker network indeed, but that's it.

With the publishing done, it will start giving you this, rather:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS                NAMES
c4bc80e62fcb   cdbaa2128e9f   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   5 seconds ago        Up 2 seconds                0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   admiring_hofstadter
```

Which shows that the local loop `0.0.0.0:80` is linked to the port `80`  of this container, making your page accessible.

Comment: You don't /need/ `EXPOSE`

Comment: Isn't it what I wrote, @SoftwareEngineer?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I misread it!!! It's obviously getting too late -- I'll get my coat :)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε your answer is amazing, qualitywise. Thank you for the course, Sir. <3